# how to derive Laplace transform, delta function?

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

This is an awfully specific question that is extremely similar to previous question (linked below). This problem utilized a quality of the delta function that allows an indefinite integral to be collapsed:

```
L[sin(t)d(t-pi)] where d is the delta function and L is Laplace transform. From what I understand:
```

L[f(t)]=F(s)= 0~inf[sin(t)d(t-pi)e^(-st)dt
This can be simplified by characteristics of delta function:
sin(pi)e^(-spi), but this equals 0.

Is this the correct answer?

**I am deeply sorry for the lack of formatting. If someone can instruct me how to include proper formatting, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[How does one find the Laplace transform for the product of the Dirac delta function and a continuous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210907/how-does-one-find-the-laplace-transform-for-the-product-of-the-dirac-delta-funct)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).